# How to sum all the total in a table row? JS

Tags: javascript, function, sum, row, subtotal

newbie here.. I was looking for some kind of function that can total the amount of one input type in table which is the Amount input.
I've tried parseInt function to the amount and its cell but it doesn't work.
I think its getting only the .innerHTML but not what it contains which should be the number.

```js
var entryButton = document.getElementById('inputButton')
const tbodyEl = document.querySelector("tbody");
var row = 1;

//click button event
entryButton.addEventListener('click', tableDisplay);

//input value and displaying information
function tableDisplay(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var name = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
  var amount = document.getElementById('inputAmount').value;
  var date = document.getElementById('inputDate').value;
  var remarks = document.getElementById('inputRemarks').value;
  
  document.getElementById('inputName').value = '';
  document.getElementById('inputAmount').value = '';
  document.getElementById('inputDate').value = '';
  document.getElementById('inputRemarks').value = '';
  
  if (!name || !amount || !date || !remarks) {
    alert("Please fill all the blanks")
    return;
  }

  name.value = " ";
  amount.value = " ";
  date.value = " ";
  remarks.value = " ";
  
  var table = document.getElementById('displayTable');

  var newRow = table.insertRow(row);

  var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

  cell1.innerHTML = name
  cell2.innerHTML = date
  cell3.innerHTML = amount
  cell4.innerHTML = remarks
  
  selectedRow()


  row++;




}

//adding total amount function??
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <title>Expense Tracker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-5 mt-5">Expense Tracker</h1>
    <form class="form d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
      <span class="fw-bolder m-1"
        >Name: <input class="m-1" id="inputName" type="text"
      /></span>
      <span class="fw-bolder m-1"
        >Date: <input class="m-1" id="inputDate" type="date"
      /></span>
      <span class="fw-bolder m-1"
        >Amount: <input type="number" class="totalAmount m-1" id="inputAmount"
      /></span>
      <span class="fw-bolder m-1"
        >Remarks <input class="m-1" id="inputRemarks" type="text"
      /></span>
      <button class="m-1" id="inputButton">
        <i class="icon-level-down fs-4"></i>
      </button>
      <!-- How to delete specific row -->
      <button class="m-1" type="button" id="deleteSelection">
        <i class="icon-remove-sign fs-4"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
    <table class="table m-5" id="displayTable">
      <thead>
        <tr id="numero">
          <th scope="col">
            <i class="icon-file-text fw-bolder fs-3"></i> Description
          </th>
          <th scope="col"><i class="icon-calendar fw-bolder fs-3"></i> Date</th>
          <th scope="col"><i class="icon-usd fw-bolder fs-3"></i> Amount</th>
          <th scope="col"><i class="icon-pencil fs-3"></i> Remarks</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- //passing total amount?? -->
    <span class="d-flex justify-content-center"
      >Total: <input type="number" id="total" value="0" disabled
    /></span>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [*minimal* reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a function called total(), which calculates the total of the column 'Amount' and prints it inside the input #total.

```
var entryButton = document.getElementById('inputButton')
const tbodyEl = document.querySelector("tbody");
var row = 1;

//click button event
entryButton.addEventListener('click', tableDisplay);

//input value and displaying information
function tableDisplay(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var name = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
  var amount = document.getElementById('inputAmount').value;
  var date = document.getElementById('inputDate').value;
  var remarks = document.getElementById('inputRemarks').value;
  
  document.getElementById('inputName').value = '';
  document.getElementById('inputAmount').value = '';
  document.getElementById('inputDate').value = '';
  document.getElementById('inputRemarks').value = '';
  
  if (!name || !amount || !date || !remarks) {
    alert("Please fill all the blanks")
    return;
  }

  name.value = " ";
  amount.value = " ";
  date.value = " ";
  remarks.value = " ";
  
  var table = document.getElementById('displayTable');

  var newRow = table.insertRow(row);

  var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

  cell1.innerHTML = name
  cell2.innerHTML = date
  cell3.innerHTML = amount
  cell4.innerHTML = remarks
  
  total()


  row++;
}

function total(){
    var table = document.getElementById('displayTable');
    let total = 0
    for(let i = 1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
        total+=Number(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerText)
    }
    const totalInput = document.getElementById('total')
    totalInput.value=total

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate your answer :)